# Why did glm function return this warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I generated some artificial data to perform a regression analysis.

```
n=500
set.seed(100)
x1=seq(from=-3,to=3,length.out = n)
a=rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=0.2)
z=1+2*x1+a
p=1/(1+exp(-z))
y=(p>=(runif(n,min=0.4,max=0.6)))*1
X=data.frame(x1=x1,y=y)
K=glm(formula=y~x1,data=X,family=binomial(link="logit"))
p_fit=1/(1+exp(-(K$coefficients[1]+K$coefficients[2]*x1)))

ggplot()+xlab("x1")+ylab("y")+facet_grid()+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x1,y), aes(x=x1, y=y),size=4)+
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x1,p), aes(x=x1, y=p,color='simulation'),size=1.2)+
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x1,p_fit), aes(x=x1, y=p_fit,color='fit'),size=1.5)+
  theme(legend.position =c(0.8,0.5),legend.title = element_blank())+
  scale_color_manual(values =c(rgb(1,0,0),rgb(0,0.2,1)))
```

R returns a warning:

```
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

How can I avoid this warning?

[image: data and fit]

Comment: This is rather a purely statistical question, which is more suitable for Cross Validated. there is also a relevant post there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/336624/163114

Comment: one option is to use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistf/logistf.pdf . Looking at your example, if it is only to plot.. i think it's fine.. you can live with the error